# Использование DLL написанной на С++ в проекте С#

Tags: c#, c++

Подскажите пожалуйста как использовать DLL написанную в C++ в проекте C#?

Есть готовая библиотека, которая предоставляется изготовителем приборов и программы. Т.к. процесс экспорта в другой формат требует лишние действия, хочу написать свой конвертер используя их библиотеку. Но не могу понять как прикрутить ее к своему проекту C#.

Вот ссылка [Раздел "Разработчикам"](http://gfm.ru/software/geof-02/)

Подскажите, как использовать функционал этой библиотеки?

Answer (score 2):

Что бы работать с библиотекой на другом языке, используется атрибут DllImport. О нем можно почитать на официальном сайте Microsoft.

Обычно, создается класс Warper, который оборачивает неуправляемую билетику управляемым кодом. Внутри данного класса описывается взаимодействие с либой в удобном виде.

Когда пользователь использует класс-обертку, то создается иллюзия работы с управляемым кодом.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите [Вызов неуправляемых функций из управляемого кода](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms235282.aspx).

Обратите внимание, что есть два способа: первый - использование явного вызова PInvoke через атрибут [DllImport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.110).aspx); второй - неявный PInvoke, с применением языка C++/CLI.

Какой способ лучше - зависит от обстоятельств. Первый способ неприменим, когда нужно вручную освобождать память, выделенную в неуправляемой библиотеке. Второй способ более универсален, но требует знание managed C++. В-общем, нужно внимательно изучать ваши dll.